# Storing inputs into an array from text file

Tags: java, arrays, text

forgive me for my ignorance as I'm still learning. This is my first assignment with try blocks and catch statements, and I'm confused on how to store the values into an array and display them correctly. According to my instructor's notes, my code looks correct but there's obviously something I'm missing since the console is only printing null. I'm assuming that somewhere the month files just aren't being stored in the array, but I'm not sure where they are supposed to be in my code.

```
String months;

String[][]Array1 = new String [4][3];

//fileReader object

try
{

    FileReader fr = new FileReader ("months.txt");
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (fr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            months = inFile.readLine();
            Array1[i][j] = months;
        }
        } 

        inFile.close();

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {

    }
    catch (IOException exception) {

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            System.out.println(Array1[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

The text file I'm trying to use is months and just has the months each separated by a new line.

EDIT: My text file and console output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwSsK.png)

Comment: Can you share with us, the format of your file too?

Comment: Sorry, what format are you referring to?

Comment: i meant , its only like

    01
    02
   03

Comment: oh, yea each month is on a new line in the text file. January is line 1, february is line 2, and so on.

Comment: Is your months.txt in the correct path?

Comment: indeed, same package as my lab file.

Comment: Why are you using BufferedReader. I think you should be using Scanner

Comment: I'm required to use it for the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code in my IDE, and I ran it, and i got

```
JAN 
FEB 
MAR 

APR 
MAY 
JUN 

JUL 
AUG 
SEP 

OCT 
NOV 
DEC 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

can you tell us, what it's the result that you are getting?
this is the content of mi file months.txt

[image: this is the contentof mi file months.txt]

Your project structure must be:

[image: structure]

Comment: is Your file in the path of your project?, YourProjectFolder/months.txt?

Comment: i updated, my comment, can you check if your project is like that?

Comment: you can try,copy of absolute path of your file `C:\Useres\.....\....\YourProject\months.txt` and that works, you have your file in wrong directory

Comment: for example the mine is `new FileReader("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\workspace\\MyProject\\months.txt");`

Comment: still didn't work.. I'm just going to send my files to my grader and see if they compile correctly for him. Thank you for the help, though.